# I reversed my Jquery to Javascript, but I don't understand why this syntax works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my goal was to reverse this jquery into javascript. Here is the jquery

```
    create: function (e) {
            var $input = $(e.target);
            var val = $input.val().trim();

            if (e.which !== ENTER_KEY || !val) {
                return;
            }

            this.todos.push({
                id: util.uuid(),
                title: val,
                completed: false
            });

            $input.val('');

            this.render();
        },
```

Now here is the same code that I converted into javascript

```
create: function (e) {
            var input = e.target.value;
            var val = input.trim();

            if (e.which !== ENTER_KEY || !val) {
                return;
            }

            this.todos.push({
                id: util.uuid(),
                title: val,
                completed: false
            });

            val;

            this.render();
        },
```

So my Javascript code works and I understand 90% of it, but what I don't get is the 2nd to last line that just says "val;"

I went through the debugger and tried to understand it, but I don't get the reason it's placed there and why it's even necessary?

The goal is whenever I input a value to my todo-list, it will show up on my screen. The code works fine, but I don't understand the purpose of the "val;"?

Wouldn't the this.todos.push automatically add the value to my array? Or why wouldn't I add "return val;" instead?

Comment: what does the statement `$input.val('');` do?  is it equivalent to the statement `val;` ?  what research have you done into jquery and javascript to prove or disprove this?

Comment: I understand the definition, but I'm just learning Javscript and doing it by reversing Jquery. If I were to write this without any Jquery code prior, I wouldn't have ever thought of just putting the code "val;" and returning the form input. I haven't found any resources in regular javascript that says to just put the variable name. Is that common? Because I'm only aware of return "something" vs just saying "variable name"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that previous `$input.val('');` was used to empty the input field after pushing its value to the array, but in your js code it is useless that `val;` statement.

Furthermore, the jquery code $input.val(''); refers to the input DOM element, however in your js code the val statement just points to a local variable of your function. If you want to replicate the previous behaviour you should do something like this: `input=''` instead of the `val;`

Comment: I'm not sure why my input field isn't clearing when I added `input=""` is it because I already have a variable named input? or am I targeted the wrong thing?

Comment: I got it to work when I put `e.target.value="";` but when I just do `input=""` it doesn't work. I don't understand why that happens

Comment: It is because input variable stores a value (the e.target.value) not the reference to it. So in fact, in this case, your input var is a local variable of your function. So as you already did, if you want to clear the value of your input you can directly do e.target.value=''"

Comment: If instead of doing ```var input = e.target.value``` (stores value) you do sth like ```var input = e.target``` (stores reference to e.target object) then you can do ```input.value=""```